# Reverse GeoCoding Macro: User-defined Type Not Defined

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to use someone's reverse geocoding macro to help with the functionality of a different macrobook. Here is the code:

```
Public Function ReverseGeoCode(myInput1 As String, myInput2 As String) As String

'You will need to reference Microsoft XML, v6.0 object library

    Dim XMLDoc As New DOMDocument
    Dim XMLNODE As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim I As Long
    Dim lat, lng, myAddress As String

    lat = myInput1
    lng = myInput2

    XMLDoc.Load "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=" & lat & "," & lng & " &sensor=false"

    Do Until XMLDoc.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    If Len(XMLDoc.Text) = 0 Then
        Call MsgBox("No Data!")
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set XMLNode = XMLDoc.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/formatted_address")

    For i= 0 To XMLNode.ChildNotes.Length - 1
        myAddress = XMLNode.ChildNotes(i).Text
    Next i

    ReverseGeoCode = myAddress

End Function
```

I am not super familiar with any of what this code is doing. I followed the instructions to reference Microsoft XML v6.0 object library, but when I try to call the function, the cell prints "#VALUE!" and within the code I see `DOMDocument` in my first `Dim` statement highlighted, with the error message "User-defined type not defined"

Anybody have any idea what is going on here?

Comment: Change `DOMDocument` to `DOMDocument60`. And then at the bottom of your code change `ChildNotes` to `ChildNodes`.  The code works for me.

Comment: I noticed the DOMDocument60 issue and was going to edit the code as you sent that. I will change the other issue and see what happens.

Comment: @PeterT that works perfectly! Thank you for your guidance

Comment: I would avoid `MsgBox` calls in a function, particularly if that function is meant to be used as a UDF (i.e. invoked from a worksheet cell). If there's no data, *return no data*. Or, return a specific error code, e.g. `CVErr(xlErrNA)`, but then your function will have to return a `Variant`, not a `String`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon if I wanted to do that, would i  simply replace the `MsgBox` part of the code with that `CVErr(xlErrNA)` and then change the return to `Variant`?

Comment: Yup. `ReverseGeoCode = CVErr(xlErrNa)` in place of the `MsgBox`, then `Exit Function`, yes. I would also handle any run-time error and return `CVErr(xlErrValue)` if anything goes wrong while acquiring the data (e.g. server down, or any other run-time error).